# Creating EC2 Cluster: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal

I am trying to spin up an AWS Cluster. I am running the same code I always am but it is no longer working. The code is this, and I am running it in the command line on mac osx.

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=“foo”
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=“bar”
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION= "us-east-1d"
$ /Users/xxxxx/Downloads/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.6/ec2/spark-ec2 -k username -i /Users/xxxxx/Downloads/this_is_file_being_read.pem -s 10 launch cluster
```

I get the error

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there anything I can do to get the file read? I don't know whats happening as I have already been running this code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Try replacing your smart quotes `“ ”` in the first two lines:

   ```
   $ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="foo"
   $ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="bar"
   ```
2. Your default region string is incomplete.  Try this:

   ```
   $ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
   ```

Comment: I am still getting the same error as before with these changes

Comment: Your edit suggests that you may not have correctly applied these changes.  The smart quotes are still present and you are referencing an availability zone `us-east-1d` instead of a region `us-east-1`.  The smart quotes inparticular are troublesome; these are created with another encoding (UTF8? Did you paste from a rich text editor or website?) and may be responsible for the error, and should be replaced with ascii acceptable quotes like `" "`.

Comment: I was pasting from a text editor instead! Thanks it works now.